# Arrow Function in Object Literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, object-literal, arrow-functions

I'm trying to figure out why an arrow function in an object literal is called with `window` as `this`. Can someone give me some insight?

```
var arrowObject = {
  name: 'arrowObject',
  printName: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

// Prints: Window {external: Object, chrome: Object ...}
arrowObject.printName();
```

And an object that works as expected:

```
var functionObject = {
  name: 'functionObject',
  printName: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

// Prints: Object {name: "functionObject"}
functionObject.printName();
```

According to [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&code=let%20arrowObject%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'arrowObject'%2C%0A%20%20printName%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AarrowObject.printName()%3B%0A%0Alet%20functionObject%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'functionObject'%2C%0A%20%20printName%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AfunctionObject.printName()%3B&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false), they're transpiled to

```
var arrowObject = {
  name: 'arrowObject',
  printName: function printName() {
    console.log(undefined);
  }
};
```

And

```
var functionObject = {
  name: 'functionObject',
  printName: function printName() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};
```

Why isn't `arrowObject.printName();` called with `arrowObject` as `this`?

Console logs are from [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsandmark/kx8m6e07/) (where `use strict;` isn't used).

Comment: when the outer context(where the object is created) has `this` as the window object... arrow functions will uses the creators `this` value as its `this` context

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Note that the Babel translation is assuming strict mode, but your result with `window` indicates you're running your code in loose mode. If you tell Babel to assume loose mode, its transpilation [is different](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015-loose&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20arrowObject%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'arrowObject'%2C%0A%20%20printName%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AarrowObject.printName()%3B%0A%0Alet%20functionObject%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'functionObject'%2C%0A%20%20printName%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AfunctionObject.printName()%3B):

```
var _this = this;                    // **

var arrowObject = {
  name: 'arrowObject',
  printName: function printName() {
    console.log(_this);              // **
  }
};
```

Note the `_this` global and `console.log(_this);`, instead of the `console.log(undefined);` from your strict-mode transpilation.

> I'm trying to figure out why an arrow function in an object literal is called with `window` as `this`.

Because arrow functions inherit `this` from the context in which they're created. Apparently, where you're doing this:

```
var arrowObject = {
  name: 'arrowObject',
  printName: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};
```

...`this` is `window`. (Which suggests you're not using strict mode; I'd recommend using it where there's no clear reason not to.) If it were something else, such as the `undefined` of strict mode global code, `this` within the arrow function would be that other value instead.

It may be a bit clearer what the context is where the arrow function is created if we break your initializer into its logical equivalent:

```
var arrowObject = {};
arrowObject.name = 'arrowObject';
arrowObject.printName = () => {
  console.log(this);
};
```

Comment: I was indeed using Fiddle (without "use strict;"). Great answer, I understand what's going on now.