# Weird way ES6 class method, arrow function and this works

Tags: javascript, closures, this, arrow-functions

I figured this doubt out while typing the question, but I think it still makes sense to have this documented for future devs.

Looking for help with understanding outputs of following: (primarily case 4 vs case 5)

```
var obj1 = {
  x:1,
  getX: function () {
    const inner = () => {
      console.log('1:',this.x);
    }
    inner();
  }
}
obj1.getX();

var obj2 = {
  x:1,
  getX() {
    const inner = () => {
      console.log('2:',this.x);
    }
    inner();
  }
}
obj2.getX();

var obj3 = {
  x:1,
  getX: () => {
    const inner = () => {
      console.log('3:',this.x);
    }
    inner();
  }
}
obj3.getX();

function a() {
  this.x = 1;
  function b() {
    console.log('4: ', this.x);
  }
  b();
}
a();

var obj5 = {
  x: 1,
  getX() {
    const inner = function() {
      console.log('5: ',this.x);
    }
    inner();
  }
}
obj5.getX();
```

**SPOILER ALERT!!! BELOW THIS LINE ARE MY GUESSES AND EXPLANATIONS!!!**
Best to try these out on your own before reading further.

My understandings:

**Case 1:** Since inner is an arrow function, this of parent is considered. Hence `1` makes sense.

**Case 2:** Semantically, I don't see any difference between Case 1 and Case 2. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

That is, `{getX(){}}` vs `{getX: function(){}}` should be equivalent.

**Case 3:** Since both inner and getX are arrow functions, `this` represents that of window scope and hence accordingly the output should be `undefined`.

**Case 4:** Since call to inner function does not have object associated, it's this refers to parent method's `this` which implies same as that of `a`. Hence, output is 1.

**Case 5:** Since call to inner function does not have object associated, it's this refers to parent method's `this` which implies same as <strike>`obj4`</strike>`obj5`. Hence output should be 1.

**NOTE: Case 5 output is `undefined`. Need help understanding this.**

**NOTE 2:** In console of new browser tab, copy paste only Case 5. You will see `undefined`. While if you copy paste all of these cases together, output for Case 5 will be 1.

Comment: "*Case 4: Since call to inner function does not have object associated, it's this refers to parent method's this*" - no. The [value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is determined by the call `b()` or `a()`, which don't pass any context, and defaults to the global object therefore (use strict mode!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Comment: A Q&A about Case 3: [Arrow Function in Object Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36717376/4642212).

Comment: Related: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - thanks for your comment. I tried again different scenarios on both Chrome and Safari and then added Note 2 in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You might just print out `this` instead of `this.x`, it’d be easier to understand. Case 1-3 `this` refers to `obj_n`, while case 4 and 5 it refers to `window` global object.

`this` context, for non-arrow normal `function() {}`, is not bound at declaration. It is not determined until when the function is called. And when function is called it is kind of a requirement to *explicitly* specify what `this` should be, by using one of:

1. `contextObject.methodName()` syntax, if available
2. `functionName.call(context)` or `functionName.apply(context)`

If such specification is not provided, then in sloppy mode js, `this` would fallback to be the `window` global object, in strict mode js, it would be `undefined`.

**It does not** “refers to parent method's `this`”.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that `inner();` (inside `getX` in case 5) is called _without context_ and that’s the reason why the `this` inside the `const inner` function is `window` (or `globalThis`, or `undefined` in strict mode)? The `this` is solely taken from context binding, not from call scope, right? E.g. if there was a fictitious `magicObject` and the call was actually `magicObject.inner();`, then `this` in that function would’ve referred to `magicObject`, just as it would with `inner.call(magicObject)`, correct?

Comment: To expand on the second paragraph a bit: it’s not enough for a function to be a property of something, e.g. `const obj = { x: 1, getX: function(){ return this.x; } }, myGetX = obj.getX; myGetX();` results in `undefined` because `myGetX();` is a call without a binding context. The `obj` [context got lost](/q/30486345/4642212) at the variable assignment `myGetX = obj.getX`, although you may assume that `obj` somehow “sticks” to `getX` because it’s been defined inside of it — but no: `getX` is simply a regular function that has no knowledge of `obj`, unless it gets called with it as context.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, your understanding is totally correct!

Answer (score -2):

Reason: In case 5, because inner method is not associated with any object when called, it's `this` refers to parent method's `this`. Here, parent method's `this` implies `this` of the method where all of the code is encapsulated in. Quite an interesting, I would say, "glitch".

To understand it better:

```
function main() {
  this.x = 15;
  var obj5 = {
    x: 1,
    getX() {
      const inner = function() {
        console.log('5: ',this.x);
      }
      inner();
    }
  }
  obj5.getX();
}
main();
```

prints: `5: 15`

Comment: You might just print out `this` instead of `this.x`, it’d be easier to understand. Case 1-3 `this` refers to `obj_n`, while case 4 and 5 it refers to `window` global object. It **does not** “refers to parent method's `this`”.

Comment: 1. This is not a "glitch", it's how the `this` keyword works 2. your explanation is misleading - there is no direct tlink between the `this` when calling `inner` and the `this` of `main`. It just happens that both are `window` because neither will have `this` set to anything and the code is not running in strict mode. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)